# Why the ternary operator is not working this way?

Tags: c#, .net, logic, ternary-operator

Why does it not compile? What is wrong in the following code?

```
(_DbContext == null) ? return _DbContext = new ProductAndCategoryEntities() : return _DbContext;
```

If I restate it in terms of if it compiles:

```
 if (_DbContext == null)
                   return _DbContext = new ProductAndCategoryEntities();
               else return _DbContext;
```

Comment: `_DbContext= (_DbContext == null) ? new ProductAndCategoryEntities() : _DbContext;` is this working ?

Comment: it is the "conditional" operator btw; it happens to *be* ternary in terms of the number of operands...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i find this code great and not actually answer to my question, but i learn something new in this... any critics will be really appreciated.

```
 return _DbContext ?? (_DbContext = new ProductAndCategoryEntities());
```

Comment: Why not do an assignment outside the method body? Something like that: '_DbContext = GetDbContext();' In your case your method return a _DbContext value and change your object's state at the same time, which probably is not a very good thing altogether.

Comment: it is singleton model....it return single instance of the class... ?? operator check if the variable is null or not..if it is not null then it simply return instance else it will call right side expression which create new instance and assign it to the variable and then it return that variable..

Answer (score 5):

The things on either side of the `:` in a conditional expression are *expressions*, not statements.  They must evaluate to some value.  `return (anything)` is a statement rather than an expression (you can't say `x = return _DbContext;`, for example), so it doesn't work there.

`new ProductAndCategoryEntities()` and `_DbContext` both seem to be expressions, though.  So you can move the `return` to the outside of the conditional expression.

```
return (_DbContext == null) ? (_DbContext = new ProductAndCategoryEntities()) : _DbContext;
```

Although, in this case, it'd be better to lose the `?:` and go with a straight `if`.

```
if (_DbContext == null) _DbContext = new ProductAndCategoryEntities();
return _DbContext;
```

which is a bit more straightforward.  Returning the value of an assignment usually looks a bit sketchy.

Comment: 'They must have values.' -> they must evaluate to values? Good answer otherwise

Comment: @Patashu: That does sound a bit better.  Edited.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator works like this:

```
return (_DbContext == null) ? new ProductAndCategoryEntities() : _DbContext;
```

**Edit**:
In your case, you need `_DbContext` assigned, so you need a second statement that does that:

```
_DbContext = _DbContext ?? new ProductAndCategoryEntities();
return _DbContext;
```

(Thanks @Andrei Zubov for reminding me the `??` operator)

Comment: yes you are right...but need _DbContext = new ProductAndCategoryEntities()  at same time

Comment: Don't you mean `return (_DbContext == null) ? _DbContext = new ProductAndCategoryEntities() : _DbContext;`?

Comment: @Arun you cannot do the assignment at the same time. if you need that (which I believe you do) you would need two statements, not one.

Comment: @muratgu: You can do the assignment in the expression, it doesn't need to be two statements. It's not beautiful code, but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

@muratgu's answer is correct.

However if you compare your variable to null, then it's cleaner to write line like this:

```
return _DbContext ?? new ProductAndCategoryEntities();
```

That does exactly the same thing and is more compact and readable in my opinion.

Comment: No, it doesn't do exactly the same thing as it doesn't assign the new instance to the variable.

Comment: That's referred to muratgu's answer where the result of ternary operation is returned from some method. In that case the result is identical.

Comment: well with little modification i find out its great  
return _DbContext ?? (_DbContext = new ProductAndCategoryEntities());

Comment: @AndreiZubov: Yes, it does the same things as muratgu's code, which also has the same problem.

Comment: In case _DbContext is a field and not an internal method variable, you may do an assignment. But why return the value from method AND assign this value to a field in the same time? It seems to me like a bad design decision. Your methods should only update you object's state or return some values (see [Command-Query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation))

Answer (score 1):

As *ByteBlast* suggested, you could do it this way:

```
 if (_DbContext == null)
                return (_DbContext = new ProductAndCategoryEntities());
            else return _DbContext;
```

alternatively, you may consider using the "??" operator. For example:

```
return _DbContext ?? new ProductAndCategoryEntities();
```

Comment: it will not assign new object to _DbContext